# Using Action<T> delegate with a class having parameterized constructor

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I have a class `Caller` having one default constructor and other parameterized constructor which I use to inject the dependencies.

At one place in `Helper` class, I have a method named `DoSomething` which expects `Action<T>` where T is of type `Caller`.

**How can I pass an instance of the `Caller` as an argument to Action delegate when the instance of `Caller` needs to be created using parameterized constructor so that it has the dependency injected in it**?

Note: Code is written just to make question understandable.

```
public class Caller
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public string CallerName { get; set; }
    public Caller()
    {
        // Do some initializations
    }

    public Caller(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : this()
    {
        // Service Provider is injected to get some dependencies resolved later in the code.
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}

public static class Helper
{
    public static void DoSomething(Action<Caller> actOnCaller)
    {
      // Perform necessary stuff
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        // This works
        Helper.DoSomething(c => { c.CallerName = "Test"; });

        // How to pass an instance of Caller which I want with dependencies?
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new MyServiceProvider(); 
        var c2 = new Caller(serviceProvider);
        // This does not work because of the scope of caller variable. I tried to "new-up" the Caller instance directly in lambda but that too didnt help.
        Helper.DoSomething((c2 ) => { c2.CallerName = "Test Again"; }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are bringing the method with the Action delegate into this, it sounds like your entire question is about this Caller class and the constructor? If the delegate needs an instance of Caller, why does it matter *when talking about the delegate* how you construct Caller? Can you clarify what your question really is about?

Comment: The problem here is that the method needs to provide *its own* `Caller` instance, not something you have on the outside. Can you provide some details about what "Perform necessary stuff" is doing? Where does it get the `Caller` instance from? Or is that the question? How to take the external `Caller` instance and make it available inside the `DoSomething` method? the short of it is, you pass it in. This design seems odd to me.

Comment: You totally can `Helper.DoSomething((ignore_me ) => { c2.CallerName = "Test Again"; });`... but that is very strange in relation to the rest of the code shown - why would you even have `Action<T>` if this how you plan to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use lambda expression if you want to create custom Caller instance in that way. However you could use a method that returns an`Action<Caller>`:

```
public static Action<Caller> GetCallerAction(Caller caller)
{
  return delegate { caller.CallerName = "Test Again"; };
}
```

and pass Caller with dependencies into that method:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new MyServiceProvider(); 
var c2 = new Caller(serviceProvider);
Helper.DoSomething(GetCallerAction(c2));
```